# Sum all numbers in text using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to improve everything that can be improved. I don't understand regex a lot and what could be wrong. The main improve that I am looking for is related with errors. I want make the code robust to deal well with all kinds of errors. I could try to run in production and wait to see the errors, but I can't. At my company, I need to try to imagine all possible scenarios, good or bad.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNdzVG?editors=0010)

```
'use strict';

var sum = function(text, regex) {

  var match;
  var regex = regex || /(\d+)/g;

  var result = []
  while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
    result.push(match[1]);
  }

  return result.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return parseInt(prev) + parseInt(curr);
  }, 0);
};

console.log(sum('1 12 40'));
console.log(sum('10 12 40'));
console.log(sum('1 12 510'));
console.log(sum('LLLLLLLL'));
console.log(sum('10 1'));
```

Comment: Is the first parseInt(prev) necessary? I mean: You start with a integer  (0) and then add integer to it. So all elements already in the return array can be expected to be integer.

Comment: Maybe not, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Numbers or integers ?**

First of all, I notice that your question title talks about *numbers*, while your code looks only for *positive integers*.

In other words, it's currently not intended to take in account numbers such as `12.34` or `-123`.
To also detect and use this kind of numbers, your function would need a much more complex process.

Let's say you really want to remain limited to integers (I think so especially because of your `parseInt`s). Then you may simplify your code in several ways.

**Utility of `regex`argument ?**

First I don't see why you're using a `regex` argument: for the purpose of your function, seems that it can't be anything else than the default you gave to it.
But this is up to you, and I'll keep this argument in what follows.

**Declaring `regex` variable.**

So just regarding it, you don't need to declare a new variable to use it: the `regex` argument your received has its scope limited to the function, and you may modify it directly. So you can simply write:

```
regex || /(\d+)/g;
```

**Choosing the more efficient `regex` expression**

Now regarding the way you expressed the regex: with its capturing parentheses, `/(\d+)/g` it makes your `regex.exec(text)` to return only one matching block each time, forcing you to the `while()` where you extract it.

At the opposite, using `/\d+/g`, you can merely do `text.match(regex)` and it'll return all matching blocks at once. Then you can directly `reduce()` this resulting array, though having to take care of the case it's `null` (like with your `'LLLLL'`).

**Casting to numbers**

While `reduce()` works, passed blocks contain only digits *but are strings*, so you're right to ensure they're processed as number instead.
But rather than `parseInt` (really useful only to extract integer part from a string where there are also other characters), you can merely cast `curr` to a number with `+curr`.

**Using `reduce()`.**

You can take advantage of this `reduce()` capability: if you omit its 2nd argument (initial value for `prev`), then the 1st step is that `curr` is automatically affected to `prev`.
Note that in this case you must alos cast `+prev`!

**Final reduced suggestion.**

Last point, you can reduce the whole code by directly using the `match()` result in the `reduce()` process, without having to use other intermediate variables, assumed you take care of the possible `null` result from `match()`.

Here is the suggested version:

```js
'use strict';

var sum = function(text, regex) {
  var match;
  return !!(match = text.match(regex || /\d+/g)) ?
    match.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return +prev + +curr;
    })
  : 0;
}

console.log(sum('1 12 40'));
console.log(sum('10 12 40'));
console.log(sum('1 12 510'));
console.log(sum('LLLLLLLL'));
console.log(sum('10 1'));
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I'm wrong, i would like to use numbers, not just integers @cFreed.

Comment: @FátimaAlves Wow... that's need a quite different answer! And so you'd probably better asking a new question.

Comment: Really? Oh :(. I didn't know about the parseInt. I will try formulate a new answer with this new code.

Comment: I can't ask anymore. I am seeing this this message that i can't ask anymore. Should i just change parseInt for parseFloat?

Comment: @FátimaAlves From the SO point of view, and to let things clear for users, it must be a different post (not polluted by the answers this one already got). More over, _it can't be posted on Code Review_, but rather Stack Overflow because now you don't have working code but are looking for how to do it! Since you accepted my answer (BTW, thanks), your new question might be based on this current solution, clearly stating that it works for integers and you're looking for a way to extend it to all kinds of numbers.

Comment: Done! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097114/sum-all-kind-of-number-resulting-from-regular-expression :)

Comment: @FátimaAlves Right, and well done. Hope you'll find answers soon. Don't be surprised I don't participate: for me it's 3 AM, so I'm going to bed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try and look for errors (without actually waiting for errors), you could use the `try {} catch (error) {}` function:

```
try {
    // run your regular expression code
} catch(error) {
    console.error("Error: " + error);
}
```

With this, you don't have to worry about waiting for errors to pop out [of nowhere] and you can just run, thinking if there will be errors in your program.